# jQuery Ajax POST failed with error 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, cross-domain, jsonp

I like to send changed data by using jQuery to a (Java) Rest service. The service isn't in the same domain.

Okay that's the java code for the REST service:

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/save")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void persistEntities(final Object dto)   { // do something here }
```

This is the jQuery code for the POST request:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://csepcchb/zedas/rest/json/save',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success:  ... ,
        error:  ... 
    });
```

The request failed error "400 (Bad Request)" (JavaScript Error)

The serverlog says

```
Failed to parse request.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 90: http://csepcchb/zedas/rest/json/save?callback=jQuery21103997392114251852_1402577652794&%22{\%22bezeichnung\%22:\%22*42017\%22,\%22elementArt\%22:\%22Aufr%C3%BCsten\%22,\%22beginn\%22:\%2213:15\%22,\%22start\%22:\%22BRBD\%22,\%22ziel\%22:\%22BRBD\%22,\%22ende\%22:\%2201:02\%22,\%22beschreibung\%22:null}%22&_=1402577652796
```

If I tried also this, without success

```
data: inputData
```

Who can help me please to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i think your url is wrong there is missing something like .com  (TLD)

example url:

http://csepcchb.com/zedas/rest/json/save

Comment: That's not the problem.'csepcchb' is the same as http://localhost. ItÄs the pc name.

Comment: There is a problem with parsing the data by the rest service:

  Failed to parse request.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 90: http://csepcchb/zedas/rest/json/save?callback=jQuery21103997392114251852_1402577652794&%22{\%22bezeichnung\%22:\%22*42017\%22,\%22elementArt\%22:\%22Aufr%C3%BCsten\%22,\%22beginn\%22:\%2213:15\%22,\%22start\%22:\%22BRBD\%22,\%22ziel\%22:\%22BRBD\%22,\%22ende\%22:\%2201:02\%22,\%22beschreibung\%22:null}%22&_=1402577652796

Comment: Didn´t knew that, learned something new thanks ;) Are you sure your returned JSON object is correct? Can you validate it with json lint?

Comment: this is a cross-site problem. If i use the same url and port in the client all works well ('http://csepcchb.com/zedas/mySite.html' instead of 'http://localhost/zedas/mySite.html') .